# How to load sources of a kotlin compiler (kotlin-compiler-embeddable) in Idea?

Tags: maven, kotlin, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Sorry for this stupid question, the answer should be obvious, but I am not able to find. I have some king of a domestic blindness.

I am trying to load sources of Kotlin compiler to see implementation of, for example:
`org.jetbrains.kotlin.com.intellij.lang.ASTNode`

I am adding this dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-compiler-embeddable</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.72</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

The only thing I see is a **suggestion from Intellij Idea to download sources**, but this button has no effects:

[image: Idea download sources button]

Does anyone know how I can download and attach those sources?

UPD: It looks like sources are empty and IDE is not handling such case...

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.3.72/

Answer (score 0):

You can enable downloading sources from Preferences -> Build, Execution Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing :: Automatically Download : Sources

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Looks like both the sources and javadoc are empty. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-compiler-embeddable/1.4.0/